Started a Next.js project, throws 404 (Not Found) in browser console
Created Next.js (javascript) project. But somehow I am getting GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found) in  browser console.
Error from terminal console:
 ○ Compiling /_not-found ...
 ✓ Compiled /_not-found in 16.8s (464 modules)

Below is my project folder structure. I have tried clearing the cache by rm -rf .next. And started the app again, but still the same error.
Can someone please advise the issue here ? Do we need to create separate folder for each page like  pages/
about/
page.js
app/
├── components/
│   └── Navbar.js
├── pages/
│   ├── _app.js
│   ├── about.js
│   ├── admin.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── login.js
├── public/
│   └── favicon.ico
├── styles/
│   └── globals.css
├── tailwind.config.js
├── next.config.mjs
└── jsconfig.json

// Navbar.js
import Link from 'next/link';

const Navbar = () =>{
    return (
        <nav className="bg-gray-800 p-4">
          <ul className="flex space-x-4">
            <li>
              <Link href="/" className="text-white">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/about" className="text-white">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/login" className="text-white">Login</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/admin" className="text-white">Admin</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      );
}

export default Navbar;

// _app.js
import '../styles/globals.css';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  console.log('Rendering MyApp');

    return (
        <>
          <Navbar />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
      );
}

export default MyApp;
 

// index.js
const Home = () =>{

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
          <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold">Welcome to AA Club App</h1>
          <p className="mt-4">This is the home page.</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Home;

Below are package.json details:
{
  "name": "atletico-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.2.5",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.39",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.4"
  }
}


Where does the package.json live?

Its lies in the root level, I have added package,json  to the question

If still relevant, would you happen to have a codesandbox to reproduce this in?
